# Can I capture an alien in the XCOM: Enemy Unknown demo?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I can't find any abilities that aren't related to either killing or healing.  How can I capture an enemy alien?

Comment: Is this out already?

Comment: Most likely this is the demo that was released recently.

Comment: If you're asking about the demo, this question needs to be retagged [tag:xcom-enemy-unknown-demo], since the options available in the demo are much smaller than the real game. If it's about the real game, past policy is that we close such questions until release date (when they can be answered by people who have played).

Comment: Actually, there's no need for a separate tag. The demo is exactly the same as the main game. I have made a few edits to the question, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there are any stun-capable weapons/soldiers in the demo - which is weird since they make a big deal out of asking you to capture one alive.  In the full game soldiers have specific gear that allows them to stun and capture aliens (although from what I read, it ain't easy!)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a [pretty awesome demo editor](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?140536-Demo-Editor-I-just-Made) available you can use to mod the Arc Thrower into the demo (it replaces some other item your soldiers would usually have, grenades I think).

Be warned, this is a fan made thing so it might break your demo.